# React Native: Implementing Facebook OAuth with Redux Saga Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I'm trying to implement Facebook OAuth (react-native-fbsdk) in my React Native application. I can get the Access Token. With the access token, I can then retrieve the credentials using `const credential = yield facebookAuth.credential(data.accessToken);` Then when I try to create a user, I get an error (see below)

**The Credentials Object:**

```
{
oauthIdToken: "MY_ID_TOKEN"
providerId: "facebook.com"
signInMethod: "facebook.com"
}
```

**The Issue:**

The last step that I want to do that I can't seem to figure out is to create a user in Firebase using the credentials in `const user = yield call(reduxSagaFirebase.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential, credential);`

When I try and sign in with the credential, I get the following error: `Invalid IdP response/credential http://localhost?id_token="MY_TOKEN_HERE`

**Login With Facebook Saga**

```
// Redux Saga: Login With Facebook
function* loginWithFacebookSaga() {
  try {
    // Login To Facebook With Read Permissions
    console.log('Logging in with Facebook');
    yield LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
      'public_profile',
      'email',
      'user_friends',
    ]);

    // Check If Cancelled
    // if (!result.isCancelled) {
      const data = yield AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
      // yield alert(JSON.stringify(data.accessToken));
    // }

    // Create Firebase Auth Account With Facebook Access Token
    const credential = yield facebookAuth.credential(data.accessToken);
    // alert(JSON.stringify(credential));

    // Login (ISSUE HERE)
    const user = yield call(reduxSagaFirebase.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential, credential);
  }
  catch (error) {
    // Firebase: Login Error
    alert(error);
    yield put(loginWithFacebookError(error));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: You may got the problem with the credential. Please try below

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
```

Comment: Still getting the following error: Invalid IdP response/credential: ...

Comment: it's normally abbreviated to rsf in the docs, but I have it just spelled all the way out. I know that redux saga firebase works because I have it working with other apps, but for login with email and password. This is the first time I'm implementing Facebook OAuth

Comment: The docs show using "select" for the credential and then passing it to the signInWithCredential

Comment: https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/reference/dev/auth/#signInWithCredential

Comment: I think you got problem with the `credential`. Try `const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken)` instead

Comment: I just updated the answer. You could give it a try too see if it works

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Not sure why it wasn't working when I imported it from a different file.